# How to do real time machine learning and deep learning?

Tags: apache, spark-streaming

Machine learning and deep learning model I know how to code but not know how to do it in real time like stock market and get real time predicted value.

Answer (score 0):

This is a simple toy example. Let us assume that for stock market prediction, you use a fixed time window, e.g the past 10 candlesticks. You query the data, pass it to the model and make your prediction (for example predicting the next 5 candle sticks). When the 11th candle stick appears in real time, query again the previous 10 candle sticks [2nd-11th] and make predictions for the next 5. You can adjust overlapping predictions by averaging them for instance.

This scheme would work for machine learning and deep learning. Of course that is just a toy example, hence there are more sophisticated of doing so. So get creative and read a bunch of research papers to see how it is done in the industry.